# How to filter a crystal report by date?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, datefilter

I have created a crystal report using a command to view sales person vice Order count,their(orders) artworkpending count and detailpending count. It worked correctly.But i need to add a date filter to filer data.How can I add it?.I tried to  add DocDate to command,but it duplicate sales person name according to DocDate. But I need to display all sales employees and their order counts.

Here my command query

```
SELECT Distinct
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    sp.Telephone,
    od.DocDate,
    COUNT(od.DocEntry) count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN od.U_ArtWork = 'NotRec' THEN 1 END) AS Artwork,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN od.U_DetailPending = 'No' THEN 1 END) AS DetailPrinting
FROM OSLP sp
LEFT JOIN ORDR od
    ON SP.SlpCode = od.SlpCode
GROUP BY
    sp.SlpCode,
    sp.SlpName,
    od.DocDate,
    sp.Telephone
ORDER BY
    sp.SlpName
```

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Report --> select formula --> Record` and write below code:

```
DocDate = {your date goes here}
```